# Application crashed if requestLocationUpdates is called to get new location of user

Tags: android, gps, xamarin.android

I am developing android application using MonoDroid Platform. There are two modules in this application, one is driver module and other one is passenger module. Whenever passenger book taxi, he/she will be able to view the position of the taxi on the map.

In the driver module, i have implemented two classes, one is GPSTracker class and other is NorthStarBackgroundService class.(CODE GIVEN BELOW FOR BOTH).

The method on the NorthStarBackgroundService called UpdatePosition is responsible for updating the driver position in the database from where the passenger module gets coordinates and shows driver location in the map. Method UpdatePosition gets the coordinates of the driver from the GPSTracker class which implements ILocationListener.

As you can see in the code, i have comment out the RequestLocationUpdates. Whenever i run application without commenting out that line of code, my application crash. But when i run it with comment out it doesn't crash. I have no idea about this problem. Also the location doesn't get update when driver moves.

Somebody who might be familiar with the mono-droid environment, please help me to solve this problem. It been 5 days I am trying to fix this problem but i am not able to do it.

I have used network provider only to get rough location. I will extend to Gps provider if this one works perfectly.

**Code for GPSTracker**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Locations;
using Java.IO;

namespace NorthStar.Driver
{
    public class GPSTracker : Service, ILocationListener

    {

        public readonly Context mContext;

       // flag for network status
        Boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        Location location; // location
        public double latitude; // latitude
        public double longitude; // longitude

        public LocationManager locationManager;



        public GPSTracker(Context context)
        {
            this.mContext = context;
            getLocation();

        }


        public Location getLocation()
        {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NetworkProvider);

            if (isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                // locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, 1000, 10, this);

                if (locationManager != null)
                {
                    location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NetworkProvider);
                    if (location != null)
                    {
                        latitude = location.Latitude;
                        longitude = location.Longitude;
                    }
                }
            }

            return location;
        }


        /**
        * Function to get latitude
        * */
        public double getLatitude()
        {

            latitude = location.Latitude;
            // return latitude

            return latitude;
        }


        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         * */
        public double getLongitude()
        {
            latitude = location.Longitude;
            // return latitude

            return longitude;           
        }

        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
        }


        public void OnProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
        }


        public void OnProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
        }


        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }


        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }


    }
}
```

**Code for NorthStarBrackgroundService**

UpdatePosition is called every 20 seconds as the timer has been set for that.
I have create an object of the GPSTracker class and set the value of Latitude and Longitude which is sent to the database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Preferences;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using NorthStar.Driver.Application;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Requests;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Results;

namespace NorthStar.Driver
{
    [Service]
    public class NorthStarBackgroundService : Service
    {
        private string driverId;
        private System.Timers.Timer timer;

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(20000);
            timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;              
        }

        void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(UpdatePosition);
        }

        public override void OnStart(Intent intent, int startId)
        {
            base.OnStart(intent, startId);

            driverId = intent.GetStringExtra("driverId");

            timer.Start();
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            timer.Stop();
        }

        private void UpdatePosition(object data)
        {

            ConnectToSever api = new ConnectToSever(Helper.GetServer(ApplicationContext));

            GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(ApplicationContext);

            var pos = new DriverPosition() { Latitude = gps.latitude, Longitude = gps.longitude, DriverId = driverId };
            try
            {
                api.UpdatePosition(pos);
            }
            catch
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_update1", "update driver failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea which point I have gone wrong that makes the app crash.
Any hint on this will be so grateful.

**Log Cat Output**

```
I/EXC_logstart(  306): **************** starting driver module ****************
I/ActivityManager(   60): Displayed activity MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.Activity1: 6632 ms (total 6632 ms)
D/dalvikvm(  128): GC_EXPLICIT freed 201 objects / 9848 bytes in 188ms
D/dalvikvm(  120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3163 objects / 207880 bytes in 144ms
D/dalvikvm(  120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 935 objects / 60072 bytes in 172ms
W/KeyCharacterMap(  306): No keyboard for id 0
W/KeyCharacterMap(  306): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
I/ARMAssembler(   60): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x3bce60:0x3bcf1c] in 8041202 ns
I/ActivityManager(   60): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.MainActivity (has extras) }
I/ActivityManager(   60): Displayed activity MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.MainActivity: 1216 ms (total 1216 ms)
E/mono    (  306): 
E/mono    (  306): Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.
E/mono    (  306):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (  306):   at Android.Content.ContextWrapper.GetSystemService (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (  306):   at NorthStar.Driver.GPSTracker.getLocation () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (  306):   at NorthStar.Driver.GPSTracker..ctor (Android.Content.Context context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (  306):   at NorthStar.Driver.MainActivity.RequestWork () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (  306):   at NorthStar.Driver.MainActivity.<OnCreate>b__2 (System.Object x) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (  306):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
E/mono    (  306): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/mono    (  306):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:363)
E/mono    (  306):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
E/mono    (  306): 
D/Zygote  (   33): Process 306 exited cleanly (255)
I/ActivityManager(   60): Process MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver (pid 306) has died.
I/WindowManager(   60): WIN DEATH: Window{45103638 MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.Activity1 paused=false}
I/WindowManager(   60): WIN DEATH: Window{4511aac0 MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.MainActivity paused=false}
W/ActivityManager(   60): Scheduling restart of crashed service MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.NorthStarBackgroundService in 5000ms
I/ActivityManager(   60): Start proc MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver for activity MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.Activity1: pid=320 uid=10042 gids={3003, 1015}
I/UsageStats(   60): Unexpected resume of MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver while already resumed in MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver
I/ActivityThread(  320): Publishing provider MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
D/dalvikvm(  320): Trying to load lib /data/data/MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44edf660
D/dalvikvm(  320): Added shared lib /data/data/MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44edf660
E/mono    (  320): WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
E/mono    (  320): Using default runtime: v2.0.50727
I/monodroid-gc(  320): environment supports jni NewWeakGlobalRef
W/monodroid-gc(  320): GREF GC Threshold: 1800
I/EXC_logstart(  320): **************** starting driver module ****************
W/InputManagerService(   60): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 306 uid 10042
I/ActivityManager(   60): Displayed activity MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.Activity1: 4214 ms (total 4214 ms)
I/MonoDroid(  320): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I/MonoDroid(  320): at NorthStar.Driver.NorthStarBackgroundService.OnStart (Android.Content.Intent,int) <0x00038>
I/MonoDroid(  320): at Android.App.Service.n_OnStart_Landroid_content_Intent_I (intptr,intptr,intptr,int) <0x00067>
I/MonoDroid(  320): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.0333e05f-221e-4109-91bd-6a13aa2251bd (intptr,intptr,intptr,int) <0x0003b>
E/mono    (  320): 
E/mono    (  320): Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
E/mono    (  320):   at NorthStar.Driver.NorthStarBackgroundService.OnStart (Android.Content.Intent intent, Int32 startId) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (  320):   at Android.App.Service.n_OnStart_Landroid_content_Intent_I (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_intent, Int32 startId) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (  320):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:0333e05f-221e-4109-91bd-6a13aa2251bd (intptr,intptr,intptr,int)
D/Zygote  (   33): Process 320 exited cleanly (1)
I/ActivityManager(   60): Process MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver (pid 320) has died.
W/ActivityManager(   60): Scheduling restart of crashed service MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.NorthStarBackgroundService in 20000ms
I/WindowManager(   60): WIN DEATH: Window{45127238 MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.Activity1 paused=false}
I/UsageStats(   60): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver
W/InputManagerService(   60): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 320 uid 10042
I/ActivityManager(   60): Start proc MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver for service MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/northstar.driver.NorthStarBackgroundService: pid=327 uid=10042 gids={3003, 1015}
I/ActivityThread(  327): Publishing provider MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
D/dalvikvm(  327): Trying to load lib /data/data/MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44edf580
D/dalvikvm(  327): Added shared lib /data/data/MyDriver_Driver.MyDriver_Driver/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44edf580
E/mono    (  327): WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
E/mono    (  327): Using default runtime: v2.0.50727
I/monodroid-gc(  327): environment supports jni NewWeakGlobalRef
W/monodroid-gc(  327): GREF GC Threshold: 1800
```

Comment: Please provide the log output from the crash: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

Comment: I have attached the log cat output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way.

What's happening, is you're instantiating a new GPSTracker every time you want a position, then trying to retrieve properties of a location that happens to be null.

Instead, I would implement *ILocationListener* directly in your *NorthStarBackgroundService*.

Greg Shackles' example of such a listener [here](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/blob/master/MonoDroid/MonoDroidSamples/MonoDroidSamples/DemoActivities/LocationDemo/LocationActivity.cs) should have all you need.

Specifically, get the last known location and request the updates as in the example:

```
_locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
Location lastKnownLocation = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

if (lastKnownLocation != null) ... // Set your instance variable for location.

// You can set the thresholds that suit you here.
_locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 5000, 2, this);
```

Then implement:

```
public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    // Update your instance variable for location
}
```

After this you can just have *UpdatePosition()* use the position that is being written in *OnLocationChanged()*.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it looks like there is a NullReferenceException in OnStart().

I'm not familiar with Services - but could it be that the Intent is null - certainly [this reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) says:

> The Intent supplied to startService(Intent), as given. This may be
>   null if the service is being restarted after its process has gone
>   away, and it had previously returned anything except
>   START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.

Comment: But if I run this application without request location updates it runs with no crashing. Can somebody provide solutions.